# TABELA TUPLA TABELA RELACIONAMENTO 1:1

Tags: banco-de-dados

COMO CRIAR TABELA TUPLA, TABELA COM RELACIONAMENTO 1:1

Comment: Explique melhor o que você quer..

Answer (score 1):

Como a pergunta tem pouco conteúdo, etão uma imagem vale mais que mil palavras.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais detalhes [Aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/exemplo-pratico-regras-e-tipos-de-relacionamentos-sql-server-2008-parte-3/18409).